# Error while displaying image returned by API

Tags: javascript, html

```
async function scan() {
        const url =
          "https://youtube-thumbnail-downloader1.p.rapidapi.com/api/Thumbnail/GetThumbnail?youtubeLink=https%3A%2F%2Fyoutu.be%2Fjw0F5UFImfY";
        const options = {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            "X-RapidAPI-Key":
              "b54739a76emsh4acae4b362f10a7p17b7d8jsn58665918e429",
            "X-RapidAPI-Host": "youtube-thumbnail-downloader1.p.rapidapi.com",
          },
        };

        try {

          const response = await fetch(url, options);
          const result = await response.text();
          console.log(result);
          
          console.log(btoa(result))

        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      }
      scan();
```

I am getting my console like this shown in image. How to display this image returned by api stored in "result" in new tab .

I am trying to display this image "result" in new tab but I am not able to do.

Comment: You can't read an image as text. As it's in binary format, you'll have to read it as an `ArrayBuffer`.

Answer (score 0):

If you modify your code like this

```
    try {
        ...
        const imageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + btoa(result);
        window.open(imageUrl);
      }
```

I think this will best solution.

Comment: But i am getting error in using btao() also in console. It is saying there is not enough character to use btao in window.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).